# Gulp watch shows a lot of eslint errors. Which dependencies are missing?

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, eslint

I made a git clone  app **Ionic 1** made with [Generator-M-Ionic](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic)

I've done the following steps to install the dependencies:

```
npm install
bower install
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

And the prerequisites of the generator itself:

```
npm i -g yo gulp bower
npm i -g generator-m-ionic
```

After that the command

```
gulp watch
```

The terminal performs normal

```
[13:58:09] Starting 'jsonlint'...
[13:58:10] Finished 'watch' after 191 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.100.235:3000
 ----------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.100.235:3001
 ----------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: app
[Browsersync] Serving files from: .tmp
[13:58:10] Finished 'jsonlint' after 488 ms
```

But several errors like this below appear later in the terminal and my browser only opens an empty screen.

```
app/main/controllers/logoutCtrl.js
   2:1   error    "SocialWaveApp" is not defined          no-undef
   3:3   warning  Unexpected console statement            no-console
   4:3   error    "mixpanel" is not defined               no-undef
   8:9   error    "hideSheet" is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  13:32  error    "index" is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
  17:9   error    "mixpanel" is not defined               no-undef
  22:9   warning  Unexpected console statement            no-console
  30:11  error    "facebookConnectPlugin" is not defined  no-undef
  34:13  warning  Unexpected console statement            no-console
```

**How to find out what are the dependencies and what is missing?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with some dependencies like **fserve** which only runs on Mac, so the solution was move to a **macbook**, now the app work.

The eslint errors only show that my project is not using the JS guide lines.